# Oracle sql*plus and form build

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracleforms

For a homework, I have to work on SQL*Plus and Form builder. I installed on a vm oracle 11g and dev suites 10g. Everything is a fresh install, but I can't find a way to connect on SQL*Plus not Form builder.

Both are asking for a host string which I'm not sure I have right. My tnsnames.ora looks like this :

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SID = CKRExtProc)
            (PRESENTATION = RO)
        )
    )

ORCL =
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECTION_DATA =
            (SERVER = DEDICATED)
            (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.localdomain)
        )
    )
```

I also unlocked the user scott/tiger. I tried to connect with SYSTEM/`<password>` where `<password>` I gave on installation and scott/tiger with host string: ORCL, orcl.localdomain or nothing, but it keeps giving me error

> ORA-12560 protocol adapter error (no hostring)

or

> ORA-12154 could not resolve the connect identifier specified (with not empty hostring).

Comment: Are you running sqlplus from the server or from a client that is on a different machine? If on the server, do you have the environment variable ORACLE_SID set? If the client is on a different machine, have you configured the tnsnames.ora and are you connecting with user/pwd@tnsentry?

Comment: I installed it on a vm running windows 7 I am running it from the server. Can I give the name I want for the sid?

Comment: Looks like your SID is ORCL. If you are on the server, try `set ORACLE_SID=ORCL`. Then out of curiousity, try `sqlplus / AS SYSDBA`. But you should be able to `sqlplus scott/tiger` once the environment variable is set.

Comment: what is the default password of sysdba? I tried the same as SYSTEM and nothing, but it doesn't work. Event ALTER USER  SYSDBA IDENTIFIER BY *** says user SYSDBA does not exist

Comment: How about a chat in the sql chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11391/sql

Answer (score 0):

Forms Builder uses `tnsnames.ora` found in *it's* directory, not the one present in the database server's directory.

Ensure the `tnsnames.ora` contents in Forms builder's folder (present in `\network\admin` folder of your Forms builder installation path) is the same as the `tnsnames.ora` present in the `\network\admin` folder of your database installation path.

You can also force a path to `TNS_ADMIN` variable and places `tnsnames.ora` to that path mentioned in `TNS_ADMIN` so that the `tnsnames.ora` present in this path is picked

Answer (score 0):

Which SQL*Plus client are you using?

afaik - Oracle stopped distributing the SQL*Plus client and now distribute something called SQL*Plus Instant Client.
If you are using the latter then the correct format of the connect string is as follows:

sqlplus hr/your_password@//mymachine.mydomain:port/MYDB

For anything else - also check your registry for your TNS_ADMIN entry.
This should be populated with the path to you tnsnames.ora